# Role of node.js in ruby on rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rvm

Why it is recommended to install node.js in ruby on rails installation?

What are advantages of that?

What happen if we not install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since Rails 3.1, a JavaScript runtime has been needed for development
>   on Ubuntu Linux. The JavaScript runtime is required to compile code
>   for the Rails asset pipeline. For development on Ubuntu Linux it is
>   best to install the Node.js server-side JavaScript environment.

See [this article](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) for more information.

This is only needed for Ubuntu Linux (it is not needed for Mac OS X or Windows).

You can try installing some other Javascript runtime such as `execjs`, but `Node.js` is recommended because it's the best available option.

Comment: What if we can't install it?

Comment: On Ubuntu, JavaScript runtime is required to compile code for the Rails asset pipeline. So, if you are using Ubuntu and wish to proceed with Rails development, you have to install a JavaScript runtime on your machine. But. my question is why you can't install it?

Comment: No no I just want to know its pros and cons

Comment: `Node.js` is recommended because it serves the purpose better than any other alternative. So, I think you should just install it. I don't know any downside of having `Node.js` installed in one's development machine.